# Why DataTable TableTools export to pdf or excel or csv button are not visible only print button is visible?

Tags: jquery, datatable, tabletools

I have created the datatable with tabletools but I'm not able to view all the buttons like export to pdf or excel or copy or csv only print button is visible.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function()
    {
        var table = $('#datatable').dataTable();
        var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
            "aButtons" : [ "copy", "csv","copy", "pdf", "print" ],            
            'sSwfPath': '//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
        });
        $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#datatable_wrapper');
    });
```

My output is ::

[image]

### Here I need all the option for exporting.

plz help.

Comment: Same thing is happening with me

Comment: So how you resolved it?

Comment: No I m stucked with it

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Chrome.

Enabling flash worked for me. Click on the "View site information" icon on the left hand side of the URL, then always allow flash for the specific site. Or go to chrome://settings/content/flash and disable "Ask first".

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'Interview' ,
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
      }
  },
  {
    extend: 'pdfHtml5'  ,
    title: 'Interview' ,
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
      }
  },
  {
    extend: 'copy' ,
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
      }
  },
  {
    extend: 'print' ,
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
      }
  } 
],
```